# Difference between select lines and control lines in Digital circuits?

Tags: digital-logic

I want to know about the conceptual difference, not a specific case.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you know so far and what your research has found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A select line selects something, like a specific chip. A control line is a line that controls something. A select line is a form of control line, along with such things as read, write, etc.

Common names for control lines include:

- /CS - Chip Select (a select line)
- /SS - Slave Select (a select line used in SPI)
- /RD - Read
- /WR - Write
- RD/WR - Read / Write
- /OE - Output Enable
- /EN - Enable

The list goes on.

Broadly speaking, in a traditional parallel CPU bus, the control lines are all the digital signals that come from the CPU (or go to it) that *aren't* the address and data, and select lines are decoded from the address bus. In other systems though that is not always the case.